# Change ItemsControl content from codebehind

Tags: c#, wpf

I have wpf control `TimeLineControl` with code:

```
...
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding TimeLineItems}" >
   <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
             <colorLine:TimeLineItem />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
         <ItemsPanelTemplate>
              <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
         </ItemsPanelTemplate>
     </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
</ItemsControl>
...
```

`ColorLine` is my namespace, `TimeLineItem` is my `UserControl`. Currently i bind `ItemsSource` to my `TimeLineViewModel` (viewmodel for `TimeLineControl`):

```
        ...
        private ObservableCollection<TimeLineItemViewModel> _timeLineItems;
        public ObservableCollection<TimeLineItemViewModel> TimeLineItems
        {
            get { return _timeLineItems; }
            private set
            {
                if (_timeLineItems == value) return;
                _timeLineItems = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(() => TimeLineItems);
            }
        }
        ...
```

I use it to change number of `TimeLineItems` in `ItemsControl` dynamicaly.

But i want to get rid of this 2 redudant ViewModels (`TimeLineViewModel` and `TimeLineItemViewModel`) as far as actually i only use it to control 1 value: number of `TimeLineItems` - i know that this logic will persist in future and wont change.

So i want to have my `TimeLineControl` without ViewModel, but with custom `DependencyProperty` (i guess) in code behind, that will have type `int`. Lets call it `AmountOfSectionsProperty`. When `AmountOfSectionsProperty` will change, it changes number of `TimeLineItems` in `ItemsControl` to its value.

I implement this property like this:

```
 public readonly static DependencyProperty AmountOfSectionsProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("AmountOfSections",
            typeof(int),
            typeof(TimeLineControl),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(1, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsParentMeasure, AmountOfSectionsChangedCallback, CoerceAmountOfSectionsCallback));

        private static object CoerceAmountOfSectionsCallback(DependencyObject dependencyObject, object baseValue)
        {
            var current = (int)baseValue;
            if (current < 1) current = 1;
            if (current > 24) current = 24;
            return current;
        }

        private static void AmountOfSectionsChangedCallback(DependencyObject dependencyObject, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs dependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public int AmountOfSections 
        {
            get { return (int)GetValue(AmountOfSectionsProperty); }
            set { SetValue(AmountOfSectionsProperty, value); }
        }
```

It should be in 1..24 range. But i kinda stuck with actual binding - how should looks my callback method, to change number of `ItemsControl` items?

Comment: *But i kinda stuck with actual binding - how should looks my callback method, to change number of ItemsControl items?*... what is it that you actually want?

Comment: @Sheridan i want: i bind int varible to TimeLineControl property and number of items in its own ItemsControl changes with this variable.